# Why Image_tag produces "images/..." instead of "assets/...."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

Rails version: 5.2.4

Ruby version 2.6.10

Per ["image_tag" documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag), it should produce image tag with url: "/assets/...", but when I try in rails console, it produces the url "/images/..."(the screenshot below), it make my website cannot show. How can I make it works correctly?

[image]
Also the "/assets/..." url can load the image, but "images/..." cannot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's a lot of context loaded by Rails for those helper methods to work, you can't just `include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` as you've done.  Instead call the helper on the `helper` object in the rails console:

```
[1] pry(main)> helper.image_tag("foo.jpg")
=> "<img src=\"/assets/foo-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.jpg\" />"
```